# HTTP response unrecognized text

Tags: java, .net, xml, http, lotus

I have a lotus notes java agent in which I receive a XML, parse it and send a response back with XML as content:

```
                pw.println("Content-Type: text/xml");
                pw.println("charset: UTF-8");
                pw.print("\r\n");
                pw.println("<cXML payloadID=\"" + payload + "\" xml:lang=\"en\"" + " timestamp=\"" + timestamp + "\" >" + "<Response><Status code=\"200\" text=\"OK\" /></Response></cXML>"  );
```

I checked how the response content will look like and i see this:

```
<cXML payloadID="1449750433..595@" xml:lang="en" timestamp="2015-12-10T12:27:13"><Response><Status code="200" text="OK"/></Response></cXML>
```

but if i check wireshark then I see this:

[image]

Why I get this unrecognized text.

And B the receiving host which gets my response back is an .net application, this .net application receives this error:
[image]

Anyone that can help me.

Thank you

Changed code to:

```
                  pw.println("Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8\r\n"); 

                 pw.println("<cXML payloadID=\"" + payload + "\" xml:lang=\"en\"" + " timestamp=\"" + timestamp + "\" >" + "<Response><Status code=\"200\" text=\"OK\" /></Response></cXML>"  );
```

Comment: Read the error it is very specific.  It looks like you terminate the header with 0x0D and you need 0x0D 0x0A

Comment: Where do you see this?

Comment: FWIW, there is no "charset" response header.

Comment: the server committed a protocol violation.  Section=ResponseHeader Detail=CR must be followed by LF.  Are you still getting this error?

Comment: yes jdweng still getting the error

Comment: Also, please post the full HTTP content, or if it's too long then at least all of the headers, that you see in wireshark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTTP headers require CR+LF (Windows-style) line endings. Try putting the line endings in manually, e.g.:

```
pw.print("Content-Type: text/xml\r\n");
```

and then mark the end of the header with an empty line:

```
pw.print("\r\n");
```

Comment: i tried the following(see code in my question) did not work

Comment: I tried, nothing worked. But if i use println then it automatically puts \r\n in the headers please have a look at my question i have edited it

Comment: It's an odd error message if the code really is only sending CR+LF. Maybe change the last line to print as well, just in case println really is only adding LFs (as it would on Linux).

Comment: Also, try fixing how you supply the charset - it should be one line: `"Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8\r\n"`